# How to group multiple objects

Tags: vb.net

I have been searching for a method to group multiple objects to change a common value but have not been successful. I have been forced to do things like this:

```
Label10.Visible = True
Label11.Visible = True
Label12.Visible = True
Label13.Visible = True
Label14.Visible = True
RectangleShape8.Visible = True
RectangleShape9.Visible = True
RectangleShape10.Visible = True
RectangleShape11.Visible = True
```

Ect, Is there a method to group, or declare multiple objects to refer to all of them at the same time? I have attempted to declare but i was unsuccessful. Thanks for your help in advanced.

Comment: What language/ framework are you using? You should probably put all your `Label`s and `RectangleShape`s in arrays and loop over them.

Comment: I am using visual basic ATM, I was trying to ask an easier way to refer to many objects as one, Like; Declare Labels As Label1, Label2, Label3, Label4

Comment: I don't know VB, but search for arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
Dim RectangleShapeGroup() As String = {"RectangleShape8", "RectangleShape9", "RectangleShape10", "RectangleShape11"}
Dim LabelGroup() As String = {"Label10", "Label11", "Label12", "Label13", "Label14"}

For Each ctrl As Control In Me.Controls
    If Array.IndexOf(RectangleShapeGroup, ctrl.Name) > -1 Or Array.IndexOf(LabelGroup, ctrl.Name) > -1 Then
        ctrl.Visible = True
    End If
Next
```

In case you want to show all `Label` controls you can use the following:

```
For Each ctrl As Control In Me.Controls
    If TypeOf ctrl Is Label Then
        ctrl.Visible = True
    End If
Next
```

... or all controls with names starting with `Label` or `RectangleShape`:

```
For Each ctrl As Control In Me.Controls
    If ctrl.Name.StartsWith("Label") Or ctrl.Name.StartsWith("RectangleShape") Then
        ctrl.Visible = True
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, But i am having problems. The last code works well but does not co-inside with the declaration, So if i set visibility to false, EVERYTHING with a label disappears, Also it does not for some reason affect rectangle shapes. I will continue to fiddle with the code you provided. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just add your controls to List(Of ControlType) then loop through to change any properties. This code is for Windows Forms. If this is a different type of application plead indicate that in your question.

```
Private lstLabels As New List(Of Label) From {Label10, Label11, Label12, Label13, Label14}

    Private Sub MakeLabelsVisible()
        For Each l In lstLabels
            l.Visible = True
        Next
    End Sub
```